# Formik - How to check onChange fireEvent for <select> field?

Tags: reactjs, select, events, jestjs, formik

In React, I am using `formik` for forms. I have field as following

```
                {({ field }) => {
                  return (
                    <Select
                      {...field}
                      id="icon"
                      value={selectedIcon}
                      onChange={(item) => {
                        handleSample();
                        dispatch(
                          abcd(index, "icon", item.value)
                        );
                      }}
                      options={dropdownData.icons}
                      styles={{
                        menuList: (provided) => ({
                          ...provided,
                          height: "146px",
                        }),
                      }}
                    />
                  );
                }}
              </Field>
```

In test I tried in a normal way and referred as well like

`fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Test" } })`

However, this won't call the `onChange` methods.
How change event will work in this scenario?

Comment: Can you paste your Select component code? did you call the `onChange` inside your `Select` component?

Comment: Its from `react-select` library, yes I am calling onChange inside Select as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on what I did to make it work

```js
export default function Select({ className, disabled, size, ...props }) {
  const [, meta, helpers] = useField(props);

  const options = props.data;

  const defaultValue = options.find((option) => option.value === meta.value);

  const componentProps = {
    defaultOptions: true,
    defaultValue,
    isClearable: props.clearable,
    dropdownIndicator: 'yes',
    options: props.data,
    onChange: (option) => {
      helpers.setValue(option?.value);

      if (props.onChange) {
        props.onChange(option);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <ReactSelect {...componentProps}/>
  )
}
```